# Laravel not working on remote server only test echo working

Tags: laravel-5

I am newbie to Laravel and first time setup the laravel app on remote server, I install laravel and configure with domain name by apache config but I am getting blank page on hitting url, For test I just echo test on public/index.php and its showing correctly but welcome page doesn't work, I don't know where I am making mistake.
This is fresh laravel app I have install directly on server

Comment: Question doesn't provide full details of problem.. Write every details related to it.. like.. What kind of server.? Laravel Version..? How did you installed it (via terminal, via 3rd party app or anything else)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question was vague. 
Have you configure the ***route.php*** to your view **welcome.blade.php**